# Push Is Not A Function, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component that's state I'm trying to use in other components, it has to be used in multiple components so i'm switching it to redux. Right now using the same function that works in my component, I am getting the error 'newUsers.push is not a function'

Below is my redux action:

```
import { FETCH_USERS_TO_ADD } from './types';
import axios from 'axios'


export const fetchUsersToAdd = () => dispatch => {
var userBox = [];
var newUserBox = [];
let newUserIds = {};
let newUsers = [];

    axios.all([
        axios.get('/updateUserList'),
        axios.get('/userInformation')
        ])
        .then(axios.spread((newUsers, currentUsers) => {
            userBox.push(newUsers.data)
            newUserBox.push(currentUsers.data)
            for (let newUser of newUserBox){
                newUserIds[newUser.id] = newUser.id
              }
              for (let user of userBox){
                if(!newUserIds[user.staffID]){
                console.log(user)
                  **newUsers.push(user)**
                }
              }
        })).then(dispatch({
            type: FETCH_USERS_TO_ADD,
            payload: newUsers
        }))


}
```

The Code Below in My class component doesnt give me this error: 
let newUserIds = {};
let newUsers = [];

```
this.state = {
  userBox : [],
  newUserBox : [],
  usersToBeAdded:[],
}

componentDidMount(){

  axios.all([
    axios.get('/updateUserList'),
    axios.get('/userInformation')
  ])
  .then(axios.spread((newUsers, currentUsers) => {
    this.setState({
      userBox : newUsers.data,
      newUserBox : currentUsers.data,
    })
  }))

}

checkForNewUsers = (e) => {

  for (let newUser of this.state.newUserBox){
    newUserIds[newUser.id] = newUser.id
  }
  for (let user of this.state.userBox){
    if(!newUserIds[user.staffID]){
      newUsers.push(user)
    }
  }
  this.setState({
    usersToBeAdded:newUsers
  })
  console.log(newUsers)
}

<UpdateUsersButton onClick={this.checkForNewUsers}/>
```

When user is consoled it returns an array like this:

```
Array(10)
0: {staffID: 1, dept: "Junior Web Developer", email: "manasaN@tpionline.com", name: "manasa", password: "$2y$10$/zYS7OhzwdLOi6Slzc3xxxxxiY0y1J6MjnLCN24GmZ3rMHWUS"}
1: {staffID: 2, dept: "Web Developer", email: "juliof@tpionline.net", name: "Julio Fajardo", password: "$2y$10$MphAC8aRY2uzs1Zxxxxxnd7t0KukEkvGbx5Y4van.Da6"}
```

Comment: I don't see `newUsers` created in `this.state`. Also, you're not trying to access the `newUsers` in `this.state`. Just some local variable named that. The only place I see `newUsers` created is in `fetchUsersToAdd `

Comment: I didnt post it, its edited now. In the component the code works, in redux im having issues.

Comment: `newUsers` gets shadowed in the arrow function and isn't what you think it is anymore.  Don't reuse variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because `newUsers` gets shadowed in the arrow function and isn't what you think it is anymore.  Don't reuse variable names.

Try this:

```
import { FETCH_USERS_TO_ADD } from './types';
import axios from 'axios'


export const fetchUsersToAdd = () => dispatch => {
var userBox = [];
var newUserBox = [];
let newUserIds = {};
let newUsersArr = []; // Make unique

    axios.all([
        axios.get('/updateUserList'),
        axios.get('/userInformation')
        ])
        .then(axios.spread((newUsers, currentUsers) => { // Was shadowed here
            userBox.push(newUsers.data)
            newUserBox.push(currentUsers.data)
            for (let newUser of newUserBox){
                newUserIds[newUser.id] = newUser.id
              }
              for (let user of userBox){
                if(!newUserIds[user.staffID]){
                console.log(user)
                  newUsersArr.push(user)
                }
              }
        })).then(dispatch({
            type: FETCH_USERS_TO_ADD,
            payload: newUsersArr
        }))


}
```